# Pandas: Keep rows according to the changes of one column w/r to other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series with two variables (col_2 and col_3) in time. I want to detect the changes in the association between col_2 and col_3 for each value of col_2 and filter the DataFrame. It's kind of hard to explain my problem, so I'll use this example. Consider that I have the following DataFrame where col_1 is time and col_2 and col_3 are strings.

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3
t_1   |   A   | a_1
t_2   |   A   | a_1
t_3   |   B   | b_1
t_4   |   A   | a_1
t_5   |   A   | a_2
t_6   |   A   | a_2
t_7   |   B   | b_2
t_8   |   A   | a_1
```

After the operation, I want to detect the changes in col_3 w/r to col_2 values. I want to get the following result.

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3
t_1   |   A   | a_1

t_3   |   B   | b_1

t_5   |   A   | a_2

t_7   |   B   | b_2
t_8   |   A   | a_1
```

I've searched previous approaches but I've found that they focus on changes of just one column. I'd appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Comment: That's because the previous associated col_3 of 'A' was also a_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col_2', 'col_1'])
df = df[df[['col_2', 'col_3']].ne(df[['col_2', 'col_3']].shift(1)).any(axis=1)].sort_values('col_1')
```

or easier way :

```
df = df.groupby('col_2').apply(lambda x: x[x['col_3'] != x['col_3'].shift(1)]).sort_values('col_1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

output :

```
0   t_1     A   a_1
2   t_3     B   b_1
4   t_5     A   a_2
6   t_7     B   b_2
7   t_8     A   a_1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col_1': ['t_1', 't_2', 't_3', 't_4', 't_5', 't_6', 't_7', 't_8'],
    'col_2': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'col_3': ['a_1', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_2', 'b_2', 'a_1']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['col_3_change'] = df.groupby('col_2')['col_3'].transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()))

result = df[df['col_3_change'] | ~df.duplicated(subset='col_2')].drop(columns='col_3_change')

print(result)
```

Result:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
 0   t_1     A   a_1
 2   t_3     B   b_1
 4   t_5     A   a_2
 6   t_7     B   b_2
 7   t_8     A   a_1
```